# How do I essentially swap pages?

Tags: page-breaking, sidewaystable

I apologize in advance for the long trail of code that is mostly nonsense. When you run the code, it will give 3 pages of output. My question is, how do I get the sideways table on page 2, and the contents of page 2 onto page 3. So essentially, I want to swap page 2 & page 3. How would I go about doing so?

I have attempted `\clearpage` however that gives me a large gap of white paper and ends up being 4 pages which is not what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}       % to get LASY symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}       % to insert PostScript figures
\usepackage{rotating} 
\begin{document}
\section{More Boundary Conditions}
\label{sec:bcs}

\subsection{This Is a Subsection}

This is a subsection.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

\subsection{This Is Another Subsection}

This is another subsection.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

\paragraph{This Is a Paragraph}
It used a \verb2\paragraph{}2 header, which
are always inlined (with extra space)
and  boldfaced.

Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

\paragraph{What Is It?}
This is a paragraph.
The heading of the paragraph is emphasized.
This is a paragraph.
The heading of the paragraph is emphasized.

\section{Sideways Tables}

In Table~\ref{tbl:sidewaysT} on page~\pageref{tbl:sidewaysT} we show
on a separate page how \LaTeX\ can handle big tables that need to be
put sideways. All we need to do is to put the table into a
\texttt{sidewaystable} environment. The rest is handled by \LaTeX.
In particular, we can easily make sure that the table will take just
the available space. That's neat, isn't it? Just make sure you load
the \texttt{rotating} package that defines the
\texttt{sidewaystable} environment.

Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.
Filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler.

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
  \caption{\label{tbl:sidewaysT}A big table that needs to go
   sideways -- easy with \LaTeX.}

  \vspace{2ex}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{26}{r}}
    \hline\hline
    a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & j & k & l & m & n & o &
     p & q & r & s & t & u & v & w & x & y & z
    \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 &
    20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    26 & 25 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 & 20 &
    19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 &
    9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 &
    20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    26 & 25 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 & 20 &
    19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 &
    9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 &
    20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    26 & 25 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 & 20 &
    19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 &
    9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 &
    20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    26 & 25 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 & 20 &
    19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 &
    9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 &
    20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\
    26 & 25 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 & 20 &
    19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 & 11 & 10 &
    9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
    \hline \hline
   \end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\section{The End}
\label{sec:end}

Finally, this is the end.  The bibliography starts on
the next page.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Move the `sidewaystable` between "...package that defines the
\texttt{sidewaystable} environment."  and "Filler filler filler filler"  and combine it with `[htbp]` as the optional argument or no optional argument at all.

Comment: Since sidewaystable always takes up an entire page (table* with width=\textheight), I'm not sure what good the optional argument does.  Might as well use [p].

Comment: @leandriis thank you that helped!!!